Increase memory and cpu for gitlab runner build phase
I have configured my gitlab runner to work with the kubernetes pod. I see that my angular build job gets stuck at below and it keeps going on
Warning: Worker #10 exited unexpectedly (code: null | signal: SIGKILL).
  Current task: {entryPoint: @angular/forms, formatProperty: es2015, processDts: Yes}
  Current phase: compiling

I believe it may be because of a memory/cpu issue. But I am not able to debug as to what would be the issue.
Below are my values.yaml file I used for setting up runners. But below mentioned cpu/memory are not picked up while runners are running.
## GitLab Runner Image
##
## By default it's using gitlab/gitlab-runner:alpine-v{VERSION}
## where {VERSION} is taken from Chart.yaml from appVersion field
##
## ref: https://hub.docker.com/r/gitlab/gitlab-runner/tags/
##
image: 
  registry:<artifactory>/docker-images/gitlab
  image: gitlab-runner
  tag: alpine-v13.1.0


## Specify a imagePullPolicy
## 'Always' if imageTag is 'latest', else set to 'IfNotPresent'
## ref: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/images/#pre-pulling-images
##
imagePullPolicy: Always

## The GitLab Server URL (with protocol) that want to register the runner against
## ref: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/commands/README.html#gitlab-runner-register
##
gitlabUrl: <gitlab-url>

## The Registration Token for adding new Runners to the GitLab Server. This must
## be retrieved from your GitLab Instance.
## ref: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/runners/README.html
##
runnerRegistrationToken: "sdsdsdsdsfsfsfsd"

## The Runner Token for adding new Runners to the GitLab Server. This must
## be retrieved from your GitLab Instance. It is token of already registered runner.
## ref: (we don't yet have docs for that, but we want to use existing token)
##
# runnerToken: ""
#
## Unregister all runners before termination
##
## Updating the runner's chart version or configuration will cause the runner container
## to be terminated and created again. This may cause your Gitlab instance to reference
## non-existant runners. Un-registering the runner before termination mitigates this issue.
## ref: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/commands/README.html#gitlab-runner-unregister
##
unregisterRunners: true

## When stopping the runner, give it time to wait for its jobs to terminate.
##
## Updating the runner's chart version or configuration will cause the runner container
## to be terminated with a graceful stop request. terminationGracePeriodSeconds
## instructs Kubernetes to wait long enough for the runner pod to terminate gracefully.
## ref: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/commands/#signals
terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 9000

## Set the certsSecretName in order to pass custom certficates for GitLab Runner to use
## Provide resource name for a Kubernetes Secret Object in the same namespace,
## this is used to populate the /home/gitlab-runner/.gitlab-runner/certs/ directory
## ref: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/tls-self-signed.html#supported-options-for-self-signed-certificates
##
# certsSecretName:

## Configure the maximum number of concurrent jobs
## ref: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-global-section
##
concurrent: 10

## Defines in seconds how often to check GitLab for a new builds
## ref: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-global-section
##
checkInterval: 30

## Configure GitLab Runner's logging level. Available values are: debug, info, warn, error, fatal, panic
## ref: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-global-section
##
# logLevel:

## Configure GitLab Runner's logging format. Available values are: runner, text, json
## ref: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-global-section
##
# logFormat:

## For RBAC support:
rbac:
  create: false
  ## Define specific rbac permissions.
  # resources: ["pods", "pods/exec", "secrets"]
  # verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "patch", "delete"]

  ## Run the gitlab-bastion container with the ability to deploy/manage containers of jobs
  ## cluster-wide or only within namespace
  clusterWideAccess: false

  ## Use the following Kubernetes Service Account name if RBAC is disabled in this Helm chart (see rbac.create)
  ##
  serviceAccountName: xyz-prod-admin

  ## Specify annotations for Service Accounts, useful for annotations such as eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn
  ##
  ## ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/specify-service-account-role.html
  ##
  # serviceAccountAnnotations: {}

## Configure integrated Prometheus metrics exporter
## ref: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/monitoring/#configuration-of-the-metrics-http-server
metrics:
  enabled: false

## Configuration for the Pods that that the runner launches for each new job
##
runners:
  ## Default container image to use for builds when none is specified
  ##
  image:
    name: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug
    entrypoint: [""]

  ## Specify one or more imagePullSecrets
  ##
  ## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/
  ##
  # imagePullSecrets: []

  ## Specify the image pull policy: never, if-not-present, always. The cluster default will be used if not set.
  ##
  imagePullPolicy: "always"

  ## Defines number of concurrent requests for new job from GitLab
  ## ref: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runners-section
  ##
  # requestConcurrency: 1

  ## Specify whether the runner should be locked to a specific project: true, false. Defaults to true.
  ##
  # locked: true

  ## Specify the tags associated with the runner. Comma-separated list of tags.
  ##
  ## ref: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/runners/#using-tags
  ##
  # tags: ""

  ## Specify if jobs without tags should be run.
  ## If not specified, Runner will default to true if no tags were specified. In other case it will
  ## default to false.
  ##
  ## ref: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/runners/#allowing-runners-with-tags-to-pick-jobs-without-tags
  ##
  runUntagged: true

  ## Specify whether the runner should only run protected branches.
  ## Defaults to False.
  ##
  ## ref: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/#protected-runners
  ##
  # protected: true

  ## The name of the secret containing runner-token and runner-registration-token
  # secret: gitlab-runner

  ## Namespace to run Kubernetes jobs in (defaults to the same namespace of this release)
  ##
  # namespace:

  ## The amount of time, in seconds, that needs to pass before the runner will
  ## timeout attempting to connect to the container it has just created.
  ## ref: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/kubernetes.html
  pollTimeout: 180

  ## Set maximum build log size in kilobytes, by default set to 4096 (4MB)
  ## ref: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runners-section
  outputLimit: 4096

  ## Distributed runners caching
  ## ref: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/blob/master/docs/configuration/autoscale.md#distributed-runners-caching
  ##
  ## If you want to use s3 based distributing caching:
  ## First of all you need to uncomment General settings and S3 settings sections.
  ##
  ## Create a secret 's3access' containing 'accesskey' & 'secretkey'
  ## ref: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/wheres-my-secret-access-key/
  ##
  ## $ kubectl create secret generic s3access \
  ##   --from-literal=accesskey="YourAccessKey" \
  ##   --from-literal=secretkey="YourSecretKey"
  ## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/
  ##
  ## If you want to use gcs based distributing caching:
  ## First of all you need to uncomment General settings and GCS settings sections.
  ##
  ## Access using credentials file:
  ## Create a secret 'google-application-credentials' containing your application credentials file.
  ## ref: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runnerscachegcs-section
  ## You could configure
  ## $ kubectl create secret generic google-application-credentials \
  ##   --from-file=gcs-application-credentials-file=./path-to-your-google-application-credentials-file.json
  ## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/
  ##
  ## Access using access-id and private-key:
  ## Create a secret 'gcsaccess' containing 'gcs-access-id' & 'gcs-private-key'.
  ## ref: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runners-cache-gcs-section
  ## You could configure
  ## $ kubectl create secret generic gcsaccess \
  ##   --from-literal=gcs-access-id="YourAccessID" \
  ##   --from-literal=gcs-private-key="YourPrivateKey"
  ## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/
  cache: {}
    ## General settings
    # cacheType: s3
    # cachePath: "gitlab_runner"
    # cacheShared: true

    ## S3 settings
    # s3ServerAddress: s3.amazonaws.com
    # s3BucketName:
    # s3BucketLocation:
    # s3CacheInsecure: false
    # secretName: s3access

    ## GCS settings
    # gcsBucketName:
    ## Use this line for access using access-id and private-key
    # secretName: gcsaccess
    ## Use this line for access using google-application-credentials file
    # secretName: google-application-credentials

  ## Build Container specific configuration
  ##
  builds:
    cpuLimit: 3
    cpuLimitOverwriteMaxAllowed: 3

    memoryLimit: 2Gi
    memoryLimitOverwriteMaxAllowed: 5Gi

    cpuRequests: 2
    cpuRequestsOverwriteMaxAllowed: 2

    memoryRequests: 1Gi
    memoryRequestsOverwriteMaxAllowed: 2Gi

  ## Service Container specific configuration
  ##
  services:
    cpuLimit: 3
    memoryLimit: 4Gi
    cpuRequests: 2
    memoryRequests: 2Gi

  ## Helper Container specific configuration
  ##
  helpers:
    cpuLimit: 512m
    memoryLimit: 512Mi
    cpuRequests: 512m
    memoryRequests: 512Mi
    image: "<artifactory>/docker-images/gitlab/gitlab-runner-helper:x86_64-6214287e"

  ## Helper container security context configuration
  ## Refer to https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/kubernetes.html#using-security-context
  # pod_security_context:
  #   run_as_non_root: true
  #   run_as_user: 100
  #   run_as_group: 100
  #   fs_group: 65533
  #   supplemental_groups: [101, 102]

  ## Service Account to be used for runners
  ##
  # serviceAccountName:

  ## If Gitlab is not reachable through $CI_SERVER_URL
  ##
  # cloneUrl:

  ## Specify node labels for CI job pods assignment
  ## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/
  ##
  # nodeSelector: {}

  ## Specify node tolerations for CI job pods assignment
  ## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/
  ##
  # nodeTolerations: {}

  ## Specify pod labels for CI job pods
  ##
  # podLabels: {}

  ## Specify annotations for job pods, useful for annotations such as iam.amazonaws.com/role
  # podAnnotations: {}

  ## Configure environment variables that will be injected to the pods that are created while
  ## the build is running. These variables are passed as parameters, i.e. `--env "NAME=VALUE"`,
  ## to `gitlab-runner register` command.
  ##
  ## Note that `envVars` (see below) are only present in the runner pod, not the pods that are
  ## created for each build.
  ##
  ## ref: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/commands/#gitlab-runner-register
  ##
  env:
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2


## Configure securitycontext
## ref: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/security-context/
##
securityContext:
  # fsGroup: 65533
  runAsUser: 100


## Configure resource requests and limits
## ref: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/compute-resources/
##
resources:
  limits:
    memory: 5Gi
    cpu: 2
  requests:
    memory: 2Gi
    cpu: 1

## Affinity for pod assignment
## Ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity
##
affinity: {}

## Node labels for pod assignment
## Ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/node-selection/
##
nodeSelector: {}
  # Example: The gitlab runner manager should not run on spot instances so you can assign
  # them to the regular worker nodes only.
  # node-role.kubernetes.io/worker: "true"

## List of node taints to tolerate (requires Kubernetes >= 1.6)
## Ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/
##
tolerations: []
  # Example: Regular worker nodes may have a taint, thus you need to tolerate the taint
  # when you assign the gitlab runner manager with nodeSelector or affinity to the nodes.
  # - key: "node-role.kubernetes.io/worker"
  #   operator: "Exists"

## Configure environment variables that will be present when the registration command runs
## This provides further control over the registration process and the config.toml file
## ref: `gitlab-runner register --help`
## ref: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html
##
# envVars:
#   - name: RUNNER_EXECUTOR
#     value: kubernetes

## list of hosts and IPs that will be injected into the pod's hosts file
hostAliases: []
  # Example:
  # - ip: "127.0.0.1"
  #   hostnames:
  #   - "foo.local"
  #   - "bar.local"
  # - ip: "10.1.2.3"
  #   hostnames:
  #   - "foo.remote"
  #   - "bar.remote"

## Annotations to be added to manager pod
##
podAnnotations: {}
  # Example:
  # iam.amazonaws.com/role: <my_role_arn>

## Labels to be added to manager pod
##
podLabels: {}
  # Example:
  # owner.team: <my_cool_team>

## HPA support for custom metrics:
## This section enables runners to autoscale based on defined custom metrics.
## In order to use this functionality, Need to enable a custom metrics API server by
## implementing "custom.metrics.k8s.io" using supported third party adapter
## Example: https://github.com/directxman12/k8s-prometheus-adapter
##
#hpa: {}
  # minReplicas: 1
  # maxReplicas: 10
  # metrics:
  # - type: Pods
  #   pods:
  #     metricName: gitlab_runner_jobs
  #     targetAverageValue: 400m


The resources that you provided in your values file are only for the runner itself and not the jobs it produces when a pipeline runs.  To increase the cpu/memory requests/limits you need to provide additional configuration.  In this additional configuration, you can set the requests and limits in the same way you would with a config.toml file.
You're really just missing something like the following:
runners:
  config: |
    [[runners]]
      executor = "kubernetes"
      [runners.kubernetes]
        cpu_request = 1
        cpu_limit = 2
        memory_request = 2Gi
        memory_limit = 5Gi

There are also a lot more config options in the second link so it might be good to look thru and see if there's any additional options that would help out.
